# Adding Images to Google Maps markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I was trying to add images to infoWindow in Google maps but I failed because I don't know syntax. Can anyone help me??

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.848461,174.7633),
            title:"hello"
        });

marker1.setMap(map);

var infowindow1 =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'hey there',
            map: map,
        });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow1.open(map,marker1);
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'mouseout', function() {
        infowindow1.close();
    });
```

Above code only shows the text. How I add Image to infoWindow which will appear on mouse hovering

Thanks.

Comment: the syntax is described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)

Comment: @JaromandaX there is description only about text, not about images

Comment: Actually, the "description" says *An InfoWindow displays content (usually text or **images**) in a popup window above the map, at a given location.* - the key is, that the "text" is HTML ... HTML has a tag for IMAGEs - so, you use the correct tags, you get IMAGEs

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried <img src> thing but that didn't work for me. Thats why I am encountering this problem

Comment: well let's see (preferably where it's readable, i.e. in the question) exactly what you tried ... because *<img src> thing* and *didn't work* is quite vague - because all you've done in the code in the question is `content: 'hey there',` - no image possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is easy. Just add an **img** tag into your content-

```js
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the mouse pointer hovers over the marker, an info window opens.

function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

  var contentString = '<div><p>Here is your image</p><img style="height:100px;width:150px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/Uluru_%28Helicopter_view%29-crop.jpg" /></div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });
}
```

I've collected it from [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)